# ASP.NET: Disabling postback of the contents of a TextBox

Tags: asp.net

In my page I have a read-only TextBox that contains a rather large amount of text. I noticed that on postback this text is sent back to the server and validated, even though the client can never modify it. This seems silly; is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: what behavior are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider making it a `div` or another element that does not post back their content, especially if it is read only content

Comment: Thanks, I think this is probably what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Page Validation to False in the Page Directive. It avoids validation of input.

Comment: that will effect all controls, and still does not prevent it getting posted back to the server

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried setting the `ReadOnly` property of the `TextBox` to true?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly.aspx